# Opcion eliminar y filtros en tabla wordpress

Tags: wordpress, registro, eliminar

Creé un plugin bien básico a partir de un tutorial que vi, donde lo que hago es levantar un formulario para que los usuarios se registren a un evento. Esto se guarda en la base de datos y hasta ahí está todo ok. El problema me surge en que necesito tener la opción de eliminar registros y ahí no sé cómo hacerlo. Además me gustaría poder filtrarlos por evento, ya que se puede dar el caso de que haya registro para dos o más eventos al mismo tiempo. Paso el código del plugin para ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

```
function Kfp_Aspirante_admin()
{
    global $wpdb;
    $tabla_aspirantes = $wpdb->prefix . 'participants';
    $aspirantes = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $tabla_aspirantes");
    echo '<div class="wrap"><h1>Lista de inscriptos</h1>';
    echo '<div style="overflow-x:scroll;"><table class="wp-list-table widefat striped">';
    echo '<thead><tr>';

    echo '<th>ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Vela</th>';
    echo '<th>Nombre del barco</th>';
    echo '<th>Timonel</th>';
    echo '<th>Tripulante</th>';
    echo '<th>Club</th>';
    echo '<th>serie</th>';
    echo '<th>Rey</th>';
    echo '<th>Tipo de barco</th>';
    echo '<th>VHF</th>';
    echo '<th>Cant. de tripulantes</th>';
    echo '<th>Color de casco</th>';
    echo '<th>E-mail</th>';
    echo '<th>Teléfono</th>';
    echo '<th>Evento</th>';
    echo '<th>Fecha</th>';

    echo '</tr></thead>';
    echo '<tbody id="the-list">';
    foreach ($aspirantes as $aspirante) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> id . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> sail . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> boat . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> helmsman . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> crew_member . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> club . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> serie . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> king . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> boat_type . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> vhf . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> number_of_crew . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> hull_color . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> email . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> phone . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> event . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $aspirante -> fecha . '</td>';
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo '</tbody></table></div></div>';
}
```

Esta sería la función que muestra la tabla donde aparecen los registros. Acá es donde quisiera agregar al último de cada fila el "eliminar", y si existe la posibilidad y alguien sabe, filtrar por el campo evento, que en la tabla de la DB es `event`.

Mi idea es que quedé así (o algo parecido) para eliminar:
[image: screenshot]

Y en lo que a filtro me refiero sería esto:
[image: screenshot 2]

No sé si exista algún método para agregar en el functions.php que lo haga automáticamente o tendría q crear todo manualmente.

Comment: Tu pregunta no es del todo clara. ¿Quieres realizar las acciones de eliminar o filtrar una vez mostradas las filas o como acciones independientes? Si lo quieres hacer desde las filas (por ejemplo poniendo un botón `Eliminar` al lado de cada fila y una opción de filtro) lo mejor es hacerlo por medio de Ajax, ligando un código Javascript que recoja las acciones de esos botones para `Eliminar` o para `Filtrar` según el caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano Ahí actualicé la pregunta para que quede mas claro, espero se entienda.

Comment: Pues como te dije en mi anterior comentario: ambas cosas puedes hacerla mediante Ajax o la nueva API Fetch. Crearías código Javascript para escuchar los eventos click, tanto de `Eliminar` como de `Filtrar`, recogerías los datos de la fila en que se hizo clic para el caso de `Eliminar` (el ID del evento), lo mandas al servidor y eliminas ese evento. Y para el caso de `Filtrar` algo parecido. Luego, una vez procesada la acción en el servidor, actualizas el contenido de la página, quitando el elemento eliminado, o mostrando los elementos filtrados.